# Terraform hitting 1000 error with cloudflare

Tags: terraform, cloudflare, terraform-provider-cloudflare

When running terraform, it creates some resources then stops with the error bellow actually the list is very long it succeed to create for 9000 domains then failed for the rest

```
Plan: 572 to add, 10028 to change, 0 to destroy.
╷
│ Error: error reading ruleset ID “1c43810ed499478890cadf70a769f1fd”: Authentication error (10000)
│
│ with module.security_headers.cloudflare_ruleset.terraform_managed_resource[“6eac8cfc66757c1fb84691dd74a88a97”],
│ on …\PROFILES\security_headers\rule_set.tf line 3, in resource “cloudflare_ruleset” “terraform_managed_resource”:
│ 3: resource “cloudflare_ruleset” “terraform_managed_resource” {
```

i tried setting the `rps=3` but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your token can't read this particular resource - "ruleset ID “1c43810ed499478890cadf70a769f1fd”"

You can check this dock about API token permissions:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/api/reference/permissions/